# Allocation of memory by zalloc

Tags: perf

I am going through the perf source in linux kernel source to find out how user space probing is implemented. At many places, I encountered this :

```
zalloc(sizeof(struct __event_package) * npevs);
```

I think its located in zlib library (for fedora 18). Can anybody tell me how this zalloc helps in allocating memory?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this [link:](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/user/kolya/diablo/lib/zalloc.c)

The allocation is the same as any other heap allocation. In the kernel space, heap is divided into many freelists, and each freelist has blocks of same sizes connected in a linked list.

```
For eg:
Freelist1 - 4 bytes/block x 10 blocks
Freelist2 - 8 bytes/block x 10 blocks
Freelist3 - 16 bytes/block x 10 blocks
....
Freelist10 - 1024 bytes/block x 10 blocks
```

Each free list represents slabs ([slab allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation)) and make use of [buddy system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_system)

So, when one does a zalloc, it first decides which size freelist can fulfill this request and then finds a free blocks from it.

In some custom kernel implementations, heap is divided amongst kernel & other services. In that case, *alloc needs to know which heap to access to fulfill the request.